# (Py-cord) Как добавить view, который принимает некоторые значения?

Tags: python, бот, discord-api, pycord

У меня есть класс (точнее 2, но это ничего не меняет). Я хочу добавить его в `bot.add_view()`, но класс принимает некоторые значения, из-за чего возникает ошибка `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'q_embed', 'title', and 'link'`. Как это побороть?
Вот сам код:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.add_view(unhide())
    bot.add_view(hide())

class unhide(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, q_embed, title, link):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.q_embed = q_embed
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Развернуть', style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id = 'unhide')
    async def unhide(self, button, interaction):
        link_button = discord.ui.Button(label = 'Перейти к вопросу', style = discord.ButtonStyle.url, url = self.link)
        view = hide(self.q_embed, self.title, self.link)
        view.add_item(link_button)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content = '(Просмотрено)', embed = self.q_embed, view = view)

class hide(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, q_embed, title, link):
        super().__init__(timeout = None)
        self.q_embed = q_embed
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
    @discord.ui.button(label = 'Свернуть', style = discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id = 'hide')
    async def hide(self, button, interaction):
        embed = discord.Embed(title = '(Просмотрено)', description = self.title)
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content = None, embed = embed, view = unhide(self.q_embed, self.title, self.link))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как передать аргументы в класс, вызываемый через другую функцию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542580/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `MyView()` следует создать функцию `__init__` с аргументами, которые мы хотим передать и определить `self`-переменные:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(q_embed, title, link): 
        super().__init__()
        self.q_ember = q_ember
        self.title = title
        self.link=link
    ...
```

Ну и используем `bot.add_view(q_embed, title, link)`.

---

Использовать переменные в классе можно с помощью `self.q_embed`, `self.title` и `self.link`.

---

Дубликат [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1542580/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E) вопроса.