# Как передать аргументы в класс, вызываемый через другую функцию

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

Работаю с библиотеками [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) и [pycord](/questions/tagged/pycord). У меня есть функция выдавания кредита, в ней получается сумма, срок, находится процентная ставка:

```
@bot.slash_command(name='кредит', description='Взять кредит')
async def kredit(ctx, summa:  Option(int, description='Введите желаемую сумму (от 1000 до 100000 монет)', required=True), srok: Option(int, description='Введите срок кредита (от 3 до 14 дней)', required=True)):
    ...
```

Я хочу сделать кнопки согласия и отказа взятия кредита на данных кредитных условиях. Большинство людей работают с кнопками в отдельном классе (обычно он носит название *MyView()*). Сработает ли это для меня?.. Ведь мне нужно передать аргументы (сумму, срок и процентную ставку) в этот класс... Можно ли так сделать?

*P.S*

> *вызываемый через другую функцию*

*Вызываю его через функцию `await bot.respond('text', view=MyView()`).*

Comment: добавьте необходимые аргументы в конструктор класса `__init__`, а затем передавайте их при инициализации — `view=MyView(summa, srok)`

Comment: @denisnumb не очень хорошо работаю с классами, если вас не затруднит, оформите, пожалуйста, ответ с кодом:) или хотя бы распишите побольше))

Comment: Ну, у вас в классе `MyView` скорее всего есть метод конструктора `def __init__(self)`. В нем вы можете определить аргументы, которые затем сделаете полями класса — `def __init__(self, summa, srok): self.summa = summa self.srok = srok`, а затем сможете работать с этими полями в любых других методах класса, обращаясь к `self`

Comment: Спасибо Вам) А как *передать* аргументы? Просто в скобках у `MyView()`?

Comment: Да, все верно. [Почитайте про конструкторы](https://younglinux.info/oopython/init) и вообще про ООП, очень упростит дальнейшую разработку.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Спасибо @denisnumb за ответ в комментариях.

В классе `MyView()` следует создать функцию `__init__` с аргументами, которые мы хотим передать и определить `self`-переменные:

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, summa, srok): 
        super().__init__()
        self.summa = summa 
        self.srok = srok
    ...
```

Далее сообщение с кнопками `await bot.respond('text', view=MyView())` заменяем на `await bot.respond('text', view=MyView(summa, srok))`.

---

Использовать переменные в классе можно с помощью `self.summa` и `self.srok`.